# Supermatrices and Lie superalgebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

In his paper, Kac defines a Lie superalgebra as a $\mathbf{Z}_{2}$ graded Lie algebra with entries over a commutative ring, typically $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$.
This suggests that representations of Lie superalgebras are given by usual matrices.

However, there is the notion of supermatrix. These are matrices with entries in superalgebras. And, usually, supermatrices are related to supergroups.

I know that an example of Lie superalgebra is $\mathbf{gl}(m|n; \mathbf{C})$, while the corresponding Lie supergroup is $GL(m|n; \mathbf{C})$. What is the relation between these two concepts if one is given by usual matrices while the other needs supermatrices?

Moreveover, how these act on a vector space $V$?